# BLE changing which UUID characteristic to write to

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm very new to coding using Swift so I'm hoping someone can help me out with an easy answer.

I'm basically trying to send a characteristic UUID into a write function and switch the write function to write to that UUID.  It will just keep using the original one I had.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I have all the peripherals, services, characteristics discovered and am connected to the correct one already.  I just can't get it to switch to the correct characteristic UUID.  Any help would be awesome!  I am a firmware/hardware developer so Swift and Xcode is not an everyday thing for me yet.

```
func writePosition(position: UInt16, characteristicUUID: CBUUID) {

    var position_low: UInt8 = 0
    var position_high: UInt8 = 0
    var position16: UInt16 = 0;

    position_low  = (UInt8) (position)  // (position)
    position_high = (UInt8)((position >> 8))


    // See if characteristic has been discovered before writing to it
    if self.positionCharacteristic == nil {
        return
    }
    var bytes:[UInt8] = [0x00, 0x00]

    bytes[1] = 0x01  //low byte is [1], high byte is [0] so reversed from LightBlue app

    bytes[1] = position_low  //low byte is [1], high byte is [0] so reversed from LightBlue app
    bytes[0] = position_high  //low byte is [1], high byte is [0] so reversed from LightBlue app



    let uuidsForBTService:  [CBUUID] = [characteristicUUID]
    //new code to try and set the correct UUID automatically
    for service in peripheral!.services
    {
        if service.UUID == BLEServiceUUID
        {
          peripheral!.discoverCharacteristics(uuidsForBTService, forService: service as! CBService)
        }

    }


    //find the correct characteristic to set to and then write to it
    //go through each characteristic and look at its UUID then if it matches, set us to that one so we write to it later on
    for characteristic in self.peripheral!.services {
        if characteristic.UUID == characteristicUUID//Position1PWMCharUUID
        {
            self.positionCharacteristic = (characteristic as! CBCharacteristic)
            peripheral!.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as! CBCharacteristic)

            // Send notification that Bluetooth is connected and all required characteristics are discovered
            self.sendBTServiceNotificationWithIsBluetoothConnected(true)
        }
    }

    //end of code to set the UUID


    // Need a mutable var to pass to writeValue function
    //var positionValue = position
   //let data = NSData(bytes: &positionValue, length: sizeof(UInt16))
    let data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: 2)
   self.peripheral?.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: self.positionCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)



}
```

Comment: Correct me if I did not understand your question. 
Basically you need to write to any characteristic uuid you are getting as a parameter. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keep in mind** that in the second `for` loop, where you are looking for a `CBCharacteristic` you are still iterating the services from the peripheral and not the characteristic from your ble service (a peripheral has services and a service has characteristics).

The following code is to get the `CBCharacteristic` you need.

```
var theService: CBService?

// Find service
for service in peripheral.services as! [CBService] {
    if service.UUID == BLEServiceUUID {
        theService = service

        break
    }
}

var theCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

// Find characteristic
for characteristic in theService?.characteristics as! [CBCharacteristic] {
    if characteristic.UUID == characteristicUUID {
        theCharacteristic = characteristic

        break
    }
}

// Write
if let characteristic = theCharacteristic {
    peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: .WithResponse)
}
```

In your code you are always writing to `self.positionCharacteristic`. Just write your data to the `CBCharacteristic` you just find.

Also if you need more help I wrote a simple [swift class](https://github.com/FernandoReynoso/iOS/blob/master/BLEFramework/BLE/BLE.swift) that manages a central connection, read and write tasks.

Hope it helps!